# Can a hydride shift be concerted?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I see that in most textbooks Alkanide shifts are shown as concerted mechanisms, but Hydride shifts are not. Why is this done? Shouldn't the rearrangement be concerted when the carbocation formed is primary and not concerted when the carbocation formed is secondary, regardless of whether or not it is an alkanide or hydride shift? Thank you.

Comment: It depends upon what hydride shift is occuring. For instance a 1,5-hydride shift is a type of sigma tropic rearrangement, which is a class of pericyclic reaction and very much concerted in its mechanism.